# How to ignore duplicates when trying to save data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a categories table and I would like to import all the categories from that table
to my new_categories table, I'm using laravel's command to do this for me.
The problem is, is that the categories table has duplicate categories and
I would like to be able to ignore any duplicates.

So for example my categories table has this

```
    id | name
    1   | category 1
    2   | category 2
    3   | category 2
    4   | category 2
    5   | category 3
```

and after I run my code I would like my new_categories table to have this

```
    id | name
    1   | category 1
    2   | category 2
    3   | category 3
```

Here is my code

```
    $old_categories = Category::all();

    $new_categories = DB::table('new_categories')->select('name')->get();

    $newCatArr = [];

    foreach($new_categories as $new_category)
    {
        $newCatArr[] = $new_category->name; 
    }

    foreach($old_categories as $category)
    {
        if(!in_array($category->name, $newCatArr))
        {
            DB::table('new_categories')->insert([
                'name' => $category->name
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define a unique index on the name column?

Comment: Is this for the new or old categories table?

Comment: Remove duplicates manually, put an index, make sure your app won’t insert duplicates. Think about such problems before doing any programming.

Answer (score 1):

The `insertOrIgnore` method will ignore duplicate record errors while inserting records into the database:

```
DB::table('new_categories')->insertOrIgnore([
   'name' => $category->name
]);
```

For more you can check [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts)

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed something, but I added the insertOrIgnore, but I still got duplicates

Comment: This will work only with a unique index on the field.